# Flutter how to json decode with a string and a list

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, deserialization

I've spent around an hour looking for this solution somewhere online. I'm new to flutter & dart languages but I'm very comfortable with C# and .net. Even tho dart/flutter use C# syntax a lot of the language feels much different than I thought it would.

I have a restful API in .net which returns a json object of String : String and String : [Array of Strings]. I have an object class within flutter where I can deserialize the response. I already done this with a normal response of just List and String without a problem but now I ran into massive problem. I don't have a clue how I can deserialise a Json that looks like this.

**As requested**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      drawer: const NavigationDrawer(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(templateName),
          ),
          Center(
            child: FutureBuilder<TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject>(
              future: templateContent,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data?.TemplateContent ?? "null");
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**Api Call Code**

```
Future<TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject> getTemplateContent(
    String customerId, String templateName) async {
  var url = Uri.parse(
      'https://localhost:7167/api/v1/Templates/$customerId/$templateName');

  var response = await http.get(url, headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  });

  try {
    print(response.body);
    var sm = json.decode(response.body);
    print(sm);
  } catch (ex) {
    print(ex);
  }

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject obj =
        TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    print(obj.TemplateContent);
    print(obj.TemplateArguments);
    return obj;
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
  }

  return TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject(
      TemplateContent: "", TemplateArguments: new List<String>.empty());
}
```

**Class Object**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject {
  String TemplateContent;
  List<String> TemplateArguments;

  TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject({
    required this.TemplateContent,
    required this.TemplateArguments,
  });

  factory TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json,
  ) =>
      TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject(
        TemplateContent: json["TemplateContent"] as String,
        TemplateArguments: (json["TemplateArguments"] as List<String>),
      );
}
```

[Image of Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O50WW.png)

Comment: please post the actual code instead of images of the code

Comment: Please don't post code/text as images. It makes it hard for us to write code that fits yours and try out the example JSON. Stackoverflow have builtin syntax highlight for a lot of languages so use that instead.

Comment: There are some online tools which convert json to dart file like this - https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: My bad on the images I forgot to post code in code quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is Sample Code for your problem. Please be aware that the code is just created based on your example where your list just contains `String` objects. In case your list contains more advanced objects, we should model them individually and put into a list. But for the strings you can do something like this:

```dart
class TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject {
  String myStringContent;
  List<String> myArrayContent;

  TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject({
    required this.myStringContent,
    required this.myArrayContent,
  });

  factory TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json,
  ) =>
      TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject(
        myStringContent: json["myStringContent"] as String,
        myArrayContent:
            (json["myArrayContent"] as List<dynamic>).cast<String>(),
      );

  Map<String, Object> toJson() => {
        "stringContnet": myStringContent,
        "arrayCOntnet": myArrayContent,
      };
}
```

I have changed the `fromJson` constructor into a factory constructor that just calls the class constructor. By doing so it removes the need for the class variables to be declared `late`.

Comment: In your `toJson` you can just do: `"arrayCOntnet": arrayCOntnet`. No need for further conversion.

Comment: Yes we can but that is good practice if we have a array of Custom model instead of array of String

Comment: No its not? Dart will automatically call `toJson()` on any object is does not know how to serialize. So as long as your custom type in the list does implement `toJson()` it is fine to just have them in the returned list. Also, this `.map((x) => x)` seems rather unnecessary in general. You can use `.cast` instead if your purpose is to cast the elements to a given type.

Comment: Done. I also added some description. Please just make corrections if you see a need for that. :)

Comment: It's look good now but i have question what if have list of other model Object instead of String For eg: [{"data":"xyz"},{"data":"xyz"}, {"data":"xyz"}] can we use cast method here

Comment: @HarishSharma you could do something like `myArrayContent: List.from(json["myArrayContent"].map((b) => MyObject.fromJson(b)))`, where `MyObject` is the other model Object, which should implement its own `fromJson()`

Comment: I've just tried your solution and I need getting this massive error. Please take a look at this image https://prnt.sc/S-EN9Zvm_3xk.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist Could you show the code where it fails?

Comment: It doesn't get past here. https://prnt.sc/9NpRKBvJKJz2

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist You are not making this easy... What are there on line 54 in `screens/template_details_screen.dart`.

Comment: It just contains a print statement so I can see the data. print(snapshot.data!.TemplateContent);

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist Yeah... but that is your error right here. The `!` in `snapshot.data!` adds a runtime null-check. So your application are crashing since `data` are `null` here.

Comment: Please read the documentation about `.data` to understand in what situations this field can be null and how to check for it: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist you can print like this print(snapshot.data?.TemplateContent); it will print null if snapshot.data is null else TemplateContent it it is not null

Comment: So how can I pull out my data from my object then at this point?? I want to display it as it finishes.

Comment: You can use if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data !=null){
 // render widget according to data
}else{
  return Container();
}
You can check Snapshot State also and show widget accordingly

Comment: I used this to display text snapshot.data?.TemplateContent ?? "null" but I get null everytime....

Comment: can you share your code of future builder?

Comment: Sure here you go. https://prnt.sc/SjShBu09Rv8N

Comment: Hey share proper code here as it is not possible to edit your code from screenshot

Comment: Sure I will add code snippet to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can modify your build method, you need to check condition `snapshot.hasData`, for more detail see [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          drawer: const NavigationDrawer(),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(templateName),
              ),
              Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<TemplateContentAndArgumentsObject>(
                  future: templateContent,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data?.TemplateContent ?? "");
                    }else if (snapshot.hasError){
                        /// return error widget 
                        return Container();
                       } else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for that error code it helped me to find out what the error is. But IDK how it is not receiving List<String>!!! It says that the list is gets is Dynamic... even tho my 1st object properly is a normal String...

Comment: that should be List of String instead of dynamic

Comment: No Worries I finally got it working to an extent, I really think that this is a mission to get objects in dart/flutter compare to like C# but it is what it is I've learnt a lot thanks for the help!

Comment: You welcome, i would appreciate if you can upvote my answer if you found useful for you

Comment: I have but I dont have enough reputation yet for it to be visible.

Answer (score -2):

//map to String

Map<String, dynamic> mapData = {
"username":name,
"email":email,
"phoneNumber":mobileNo,
"password":password ,
"refCode": inviteCode,
"countryCode":countryCode,
"country": "india"
};

json.encode(mapData);

// map to list

List values = List();

mapData.forEach((v) => values.add(v));
print(values);